# Can I do a full-install of Ubuntu 12.04 on a USB stick FROM the USB stick itself?

Tags: installation

I have only one 16 GB FAT 32 file system formatted USB drive, pen drive, flash-memory drive, or whatever you wish to call it.

I would like to format it from my LiveUSB distro in memory, and format to EXT4, and finally have the partitions set up (with the swap space one), but I've had issues with this in the past.

I've gotten error messages, such as:

"Can't perform action. Filesystem is busy, try again later.",

"An unknown error as occured.",

"The kernel is not responding to the request.",

"No root filesystem is defined, correct from partitioning menu."

I have tried to partition, but I get another giant list of errors that I can't even paste here due to a current issue with my processor's heat dissipation.

However, I could not seem to resolve the problems. I have lost pretty much all hope, and I'd like some feedback on what the real problem behind this might be.

The .ISO is *not* bad, the hardware is all working fine, etc., etc., etc.

Why am I getting so many issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting right this is iwhat you want to do:
(1) use a USB drive (we'll call it `USBDRIVEA`) with the LiveCD ISO on it to...
(2) Use `USBDRIVEA` to install Ubuntu to `USBDRIVEA`.

Unfortunately, i don't think you can from there, you'd need another USB drive to hold the image so you can free up `USBDRIVEA` from being mounted (which is what happens when you're on the live environment).  Typically you'd have to introduce another medium (for example, another USB drive, `USBDRIVEB`) to either receive the installation, or to have the LiveCD environment that's running so you can install to the other drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) or [YUMI Multiboot USB Creator](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) from Pen Drive Linux to boot and run your iso strait from the usb stick. You can still run it from there and use persistance to keep all of your data. WUBI will let you install to a usb stick and run through windows or boot it up.

Otherwise if you have an optical drive, you can burn your ISO onto that then install to your USB device. That or borrow an extra USB drive from a friend.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I was wrong in thinking I could install it on the USB itself. :(